# Need to watermark word documents via aspose in Alfresco

Tags: java, aspose

I am trying to watermark word document in alfresco utilizing aspose Java utility by building Java backed webscript.

I am getting error as exception sending connect initialized event to listner instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextListner
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/aspose/words/DocumentBase

Comment: you might be missing the dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aspose/aspose-words

Comment: @Ashu, thats not the issue ...I have updated pom.xml pointing to right libraries.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

Please remove reference to old Aspose.Words for Java from your project, clean the project (any IDE cache etc) and add reference again in your project to the new ‘aspose-words-19.9-jdk17.jar’. Hope this helps you.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.